# React axios data type issue

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have the following submit method:

```
submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var token = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[0].getAttribute("content"); 
    var form = document.querySelector('.form'); 

    if(navigator.onLine && JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('candidates'))) {

        axios({
            url: '/save-data',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: { 
                "candidates": localStorage.getItem('candidates')
            },
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
            }

        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(e){
            console.log(e);
        });
    }

    else {
        var singleCandidate = serialize(form, { hash: true }); 
        var fromStorage = localStorage.getItem("candidates");

        if (fromStorage) { 
            var parsedFromStorage = JSON.parse(fromStorage) 
            parsedFromStorage.push(singleCandidate) 
            localStorage.setItem("candidates", JSON.stringify(parsedFromStorage));
        } 
        else { 
            localStorage.setItem("candidates", JSON.stringify([singleCandidate]));
        } 
    }
}
```

it loads data from local storage and submits it if there is data and connection at the same time.
However there is something that doesn't work with the following:

```
            data: { 
                "candidates": localStorage.getItem('candidates')
            },
```

if I do:

```
            data: {
                "candidates": [
                    {
                        "name": this.state.firstName, 
                        "email": this.state.email,
                        "university": this.state.university,
                        "degree": this.state.degree
                    }
                ]
            },
```

I get a positive response, form data gets submitted. However I have to submit this value (localStorage.getItem('candidates')) and when I do that I get the following:

[image]

Should "localStorage.getItem('candidates')" be changed to another format?

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.parse`?

Comment: I did now and it worked. Thank you!